# mysql Exists error clause

Tags: mysql

[image]I need help in MySQL EXISTS clause

The original table is the first pic

[image]

the second pic is the expected output

[image]

the third pic is currently my output

my current code is `SELECT CustomerName, Address FROM customers_tbl WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM customers_tbl WHERE (Country = 'Mexico'));`

Comment: And the original data are? and the logic behind it?

Comment: Trying to do something like `SELECT CustomerName, Address FROM customers_tbl WHERE Country = 'Mexico';` ?

Comment: Additionally, if you want the result to have an order you should add an Order By clause.

Comment: Please share structure of the table.

Comment: @Sinto yes but I need to use EXISTS clause

Comment: @Learning I need only 3 names for the output

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I forgot to share, I need 10 reputations to edit my post

Comment: @Jens I need to use the normal mysql SELECT and WHERE but I need to use EXISTS, from my output I need only 3 of them

Comment: Why you Need exists?

Comment: @Jens we were instructed to use it

Comment: 1) It still doesn't make any sense why you need EXISTS clause. 
2) It doesn't matter how many columns you need. What I am saying is that if you are expecting the result to have a certain order you should add an Order By clause and order by that column.

Comment: Can you please create an http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can check out statements

Comment: @Learning from the original table of 5names, I need only the ones living in Mexico with the use of EXISTS

Comment: @JohnAniez, please mark the answer as correct, if you think its helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address FROM customers_tbl Q WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM customers_tbl SQ WHERE 
SQ.Country = Q.Country AND SQ.Country = 'Mexico');
```

Here is my explanation:
In the SQL in Question, Sub-query alway have a set of result, if table `customers_tbl` contain `Country: Mexico`. Sub-query is not depended with the main query. So in that SQL, `EXISTS` condition works TRUE always. As a result all data's will be shows as output.
On my answer, I have used Aliasing for tables in main query & sub-query. And also used a connection between main query & sub. In this scenario, each result in subquery will depend to the value in main also. So sub query only fetch corresponding results & `EXISTS` works properly.

Comment: thanks, your code worked,if I may ask did you use an alias?

Comment: no need of deleting comment :). The reason why I asked was that always for answer I get -ve's even its helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address 
FROM customers_tbl 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Country FROM customers_tbl WHERE (Country = 'Mexico'));
```

Try this one.

Comment: that's the basic mysql command for what I need but I need to use the EXISTS clause

Comment: @JohnAniez I improved my answer

Comment: If you need the exists clause since you were instructed to do so, could there be an additional requirement that would justify the use of EXISTS?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about the EXIST or Not EXIST clause properly ? 
 I think you don't know EXIST or Not EXIST clause properly , otherwise you will not ask above question.

EXISTS or NOT EXISTS return either true or false If a `subquery` returns any rows or not respectively .

Please read [Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)